#  Embed videos through Youtube

Tags: asp.net

I have the task to embed videos through the youtube channel in our website. So I want some help me how can I do that? I don't have any information to do that.

Comment: do you want to embed the videos via code behind or just in a static aspx page?

Comment: embed the videos via code behind

Comment: Its a place you can upload a picture of your bathtub for embedding on websites

Comment: @keppie, @eddy556 lol. @KareemSaad I can't imagine a search doesn't gives this right away.

Comment: I agree this should've been googled first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just underneath each video is a button labelled Embed (with square brackets surrounding it).  This will give you the code you need to paste into your site to embed the video.  To do this you would put the code in the .aspx markup where appropriate.